# How to force TeamCity to only work on signed commits in GitLab

Tags: git, teamcity, gitlab, gnupg

Currently, we are using GitLab Enterprise Edition 9.5.1 and TeamCity Professional 2017.1.2 (build 46812). The build agent has a line like

`git pull --verify-signature`

Our group would like to have TeamCity verify gpg signature without having an explicit `pull` command.

How do you configure TeamCity to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Absent input from the community, here is the first working kludge.

## First build step

The first lines in the first TeamCity build step are:

```
git verify-commit HEAD~0

export VERIFY_EXIT_CODE=$?

if [ "$VERIFY_EXIT_CODE" -eq "0" ]
then
  echo "Git commit GPG signature is VERIFIED"
else
  echo "Git commit GPG signature is NOT VERIFIED"
  build stop
fi
```

## GPG signature verified

When the commit has a verified GPG signature, the output resembles this:

```
[12:17:54] Step 1/3: Verify GPG signature on commit (Command Line)
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] Starting: /home/*******/Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent_***_1/temp/agentTmp/custom_script5468853061762530637
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] in directory: /home/*******/Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent_***_1/work/c8edabae02b7df61
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] 
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] git verify-commit HEAD~0
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Sep 2017 12:15:59 PM MDT using RSA key ID 71F1FCB8
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] gpg: Good signature from "My Name (*** gpg key) <******@*****.***>"
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] 
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] export VERIFY_EXIT_CODE=$?=0
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] Git commit GPG signature is VERIFIED
[12:17:54][Step 1/3] Process exited with code 0
```

## GPG signature unverified

When the commit has no verified GPG signature, or TeamCity can't find the public key, the output looks like this:

```
[12:10:37] Step 1/3: Verify gpg signature on git repository (Command Line)
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Starting: /home/*******/Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent_***_1/temp/agentTmp/custom_script4984466249864504039
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] in directory: /home/*******/Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent_***_1/work/c8edabae02b7df61

[12:10:37][Step 1/3] git verify-commit HEAD~0
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Git repository is NOT VERIFIED
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] 
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] export VERIFY_EXIT_CODE=$?=1
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Git repository is NOT VERIFIED
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] 
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] build stop
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] /home/*******/Applications/TeamCity/buildAgent_***_1/temp/agentTmp/custom_script4984466249864504039: line 19: build: command not found
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Process exited with code 127
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Process exited with code 127
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Step Verify gpg signature on git repository (Command Line) failed
[12:10:37][Step 1/3] Error message is logged
```